# Data is not entered into the table using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, aiogram

I tried to do a shopping cart in the telegram bot using `psycopg2` and `aiogram`, but the data does not appear in the "korzina" column
code:

```
connection.cursor(f'INSERT INTO bot_users(korzina) VALUES({id_tovara}) FROM bot_user WHERE user_id=           {us_id}')
    connection.commit()
```

Types of columns:

```
user_id      | bigint 
korzina      | text
```

I'm using Postgresql.

Nothing happened with the "korzina" column. All data are written correctly (name of columns and table name).

Comment: **DO NOT** use `f` strings for parameters. Read the docs [Paramter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling [`connection.cursor`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.cursor) with a very long `name` parameter, which is most likely not what you had in mind.

You probably want to create an unnamed cursor object, and then call its [`execute`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) method:

```
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO blabla ... ")
```

You may also want to look at the behaviour of connections and cursors when used as [context managers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement).

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT INTO` command does not include the `FROM` clause, you should instead modify your query to use `UPDATE`, something like this;

```
sql_query = "UPDATE bot_users SET korzina = %s WHERE user_id = %s"
cursor.execute(sql_query, (id_tovara, us_id))
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import psycopg2

# Establish a database connection
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    database="your_database_name",
    user="your_username",
    password="your_password",
    host="your_host",
    port="your_port"
)

# Create a cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

id_tovara = 123  # Replace with the actual value you want to insert
us_id = 456  # Replace with the actual user_id value

# Use a parameterized query to prevent SQL injection
sql = "UPDATE bot_users SET korzina = %s WHERE user_id = %s"
data = (id_tovara, us_id)

try:
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    connection.commit()
    print("Data inserted successfully into the korzina column.")
except Exception as e:
    connection.rollback()  # Rollback the transaction in case of an error
    print("Error:", e)

# Close the cursor and connection when done
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```